# Using a Timer to Count Down

Tags: java, swing, timer

Trying to write a timer to do a count down (like a rocket launch: 3-2-1-Go). What I have seems only to execute once. I need it to repeatedly (almost recursively) execute until the value reaches 0.

As you will see, I have various println statements to follow the progress of this. Here is my output:

> in Coundown constructor
>
> in ActionListener
>
> counting down
>
> 3

What is wrong is that I am missing the following outputs:

> 2
>
> 1
>
> Go

which indicates to me that this timer is not actually counting down. It seems to be waiting for one second and then terminating.

How can I get this to call itself until the timer reaches zero?  Thank you!

```
public class StopWatch {

    JFrameMath myTest;
    int seconds;

    /* Constructor */
    public StopWatch(JFrameMath thisTest, int sec) {
        myTest = thisTest;
        seconds = sec;

        myTest.hideTestButtons(true);
        Countdown display = new Countdown(myTest);
    }
}

class Countdown extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Timer myTimer = new Timer(250, this);
    JFrameMath myTest;

    public Countdown(JFrameMath thisTest) {

        System.out.println("in Coundown constructor");  

        myTimer.setInitialDelay(1150);
        myTest = thisTest;
        myTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("in ActionListener");      
        int countSeconds = 3;

        if(countSeconds == 0) {
            myTest.showTimeRemaining("Go");
            myTimer.stop();
            System.out.println("done");
        } else {
            System.out.println("counting down");
            myTest.showTimeRemaining(""+countSeconds);
            countSeconds--;
        }

        myTimer.stop();
        myTest.hideTestButtons(false);
    }
}

public void showTimeRemaining(JFrameMath thisTest, String numSec) {
  System.out.println(numSec);
    lblCountdown.setText(numSec);
    thisTest.pack();
}
```

Comment: What is the full type of `Timer`?

Comment: @João: probably `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this. I have an import javax.swing.* but nothing else that further identifies the type of this, it must be javax.swing.Timer as Mechanical snail said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Remove** `myTimer.stop()` from the end of `actionPerformed`. That is what's preventing it from triggering subsequent events. The only place where you want to call `stop` is inside `if (countSeconds == 0)`.

Also, I don't know if it's a typo or a test, but you need to remove the line `int countSeconds = 3;` from `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Now I get the correct output in the output console, but this isn't working correctly yet. First, the output is not separated by one second like I need it to be. Second, and more importantly, my JLabel is not reflecting the decremented output. It start at "3" and stays there until it disappears. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) If you want the events to fire with a one second delay, you need to define an in-between delay of `1000` in the `Timer` constructor, i.e., `new Timer(1000, this)`. Note that `setInitialDelay` is just the *initial* delay, not the *in-between* delay; 2) Maybe you're hiding it somewhere else, from the code I can see, everything seems fine.

Comment: Thanks again. My timer was set to 250 initially. Now I can see the outputs generating at one second intervals as desired. However, the whole point of using this timer was to update this label on my JFrame. What is happening is that the very last line myTest.hideButtons() is executing *before* the timer finishes! My use of the timer is solely to delay this line until after everything else runs. I've been reading about these timers, but obviously I'm not understanding how to use them correctly. Can you see what I need to do? Thanks again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I just had to move that line to inside my timer at the end. I didn't think through the threading implications. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you are stopping the timer on the first pass:

```
myTimer.stop(); <---- remove this call
myTest.hideTestButtons(false);
```

so your timer is never called again.

Having fixed this, you are initialising

```
int countSeconds = 3;
```

every time in actionPerformed so the counter will never end.

You need to move this to class level and initialise it just before you start the timer.

Comment: Thanks! That was part of the problem.